# How to #define variable in C

Tags: c

I have a file called config.h with the following...

```
#define GL_DOOM
```

Then I have the following in another file m_misc.c...

```
#include "config.h"
...
#if ((defined GL_DOOM) && (defined _MSC_VER))
LOGD("Using glboom-plus.cfg");
#define BOOM_CFG "glboom-plus.cfg"
#else
LOGD("Using prboom-plus.cfg");
#define BOOM_CFG "prboom-plus.cfg"
#endif
```

But it says...

> 05-02 14:40:24.789: D/Doom(2966): Using prboom-plus.cfg

What is the deal here? I am new to C so what am I missing?

Comment: `&& (defined _MSC_VER)` <- `_MSC_VER` seems to not be defined.

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: Is the line `#define GL_DOOM` in config.h getting parsed? For example, are there `#if`'s or `#ifdef`'s around it?

Comment: @DanielFischer seems the right answer why you did not put it as an answer ?

Comment: As for compiler I am using the gcc compiler on Android NDK (So bionic)

Comment: Sorry missed the _MSC_VER thing, let me try to remove then I will update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take the following code:

```
#define GL_DOOM
#define _MSC_VER

#if ((defined GL_DOOM) && (defined _MSC_VER))
LOGD("Using glboom-plus.cfg");
#else
LOGD("Using prboom-plus.cfg");
#endif
```

I can compile that code with `g++ -E` which will output the result of the preprocessor. Let's look at that output.

```
# 1 "blah.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "blah.c"

LOGD("Using glboom-plus.cfg");
```

So, to me, this implies that you probably don't have both `GL_DOOM` and `_MSC_VER` defined.

---

You might verify this with a test that looks something like:

```
#include "config.h"

#ifndef GL_DOOM
#error GL_DOOM is not defined
#endif

#ifndef _MSC_VER
#error _MSC_VER is not defined
#endif
```

---

It's also worth noting something. `_MSC_VER` is a preprocessor symbol that is defined almost strictly by **Microsoft Visual Studio**. If you're not compiling with that software, then the expectation would be that it would **not** be defined.

Comment: +1 for educating on `-E` and `#error` to debug preprocessing step.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include "config.h"
```

that includes the `#define GL_DOOM`.

```
...
#if ((defined GL_DOOM) && (defined _MSC_VER))
```

That checks whether both, `GL_DOOM` and `_MSC_VER` are defined.

Since `GL_DOOM` is defined, either your preprocessor is totally broken, or `_MSC_VER` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The check

```
#if ((defined GL_DOOM) && (defined _MSC_VER))
```

will only evaluate to true if both the conditions are met. You have not specified whether you have defined _MSC_VER in the header file. That is probably the reason why it is executing the else condition.

If you want to log when either of those are defined in the header file, use the OR operation instead:

```
#if (defined (GL_DOOM)) || (defined (_MSC_VER))
```